# PhpStorm show usages of __invoke methods

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have problems detecting the use of a [__invoke](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) method in [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).

Example of class that is used with the __invoke php method:

```
class InitNewsletterSubscribedCustomerUseCase
{    
    /**
     * @param CustomerId $id
     * @throws CustomerIsValidatedException
     */
    public function __invoke(CustomerId $id)
    {
...
```

And I would like, as in all php methods, to know where it is used in the project wiht PhpStorm.

The variable knows the type, but PhpStorm does not know it knows that it executes that magic method "__invoke".

```
 /** @var InitNewsletterSubscribedCustomerUseCase $useCase */
 $useCase = $this->useCase;
 try{
     $useCase($customerId);
  }
  catch (CustomerIsNewsletterSubscribedException $ex)
```

Is there any special phpdoc or note for this?

PD: I use the 2018.3.3 version of PhpStorm.

Comment: Accordingly to this ticket (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34223) it should be fixed in **2019.1** only (currently in EAP stage). Try EAP build: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/eap/

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that in the release https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+191.4212.35+Release+Notes publish the bugfix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to [WI-34223](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34223) ticket, it should be fixed in **2019.1** only (currently in EAP stage).

Try EAP build from https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/eap/ page.